# Download new variable values javascript

Tags: javascript

Currently I am saving variables as such
`localStorage.setItem("variableAchieved",variable.achieved);`

then when the user loads the game it loads as such

`var variable_save = localStorage.getItem("variableAchieved");
 variable.achieved = parseInt(variable_save);`

Now this works fine but it requires me to have a first launch for my game that looks like this

`variable.achieved = 0`

this way the variables are set to 0 on the first launch of the game instead of `NaN`

Now the issue I am running into is I have a couple hundred users playing my game now I cant reset all thier data when adding new values so how do I force the people who already play the game and the new users to get the new variables with the least amount of coding possible as the majority of my scripts are 8000+ lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var variable_save = localStorage.getItem("variableAchieved") || "0";
```

The `||` operator is a `logical or` -- meaning if the first expression is a falsy (as opposed to false) then move on to the second expression.

Falsy values include the empty string (`""`), `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `0` and `false`.

Comment: quick question tho if i dont want it as a string then i should write the 0 without the "" correct?

Comment: Correct, a regular `0` would work, but since getItem returns a string, I figured I'd give you a string value.  As for upvotes, once is enough.  Glad it helps.